# Nil coalescing operator in swift returns a weird result

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

Could anyone tell me why Xcode's Playground returns nil if I put double question mark instead of single question mark for variable a?
Due to overflow result must be 64, not nil.

Swift version 2.2,
Xcode version 7.3.1,
OS X version 10.11.6

```
import Cocoa

   var b: Int8
   var c: String? = "128"
   var a: Int8?? = Int8(c!)

   b = 64

   func nilCoalescing() {
      a != nil ? a! : b
   }

   nilCoalescing()
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. You're also not using the nil coalescing operator anywhere.

Comment: but if I write var a: Int8? = Int8(c!) it returns 64.

Comment: That's not how you use the nil coalescing operator. You would want something like `var a: Int8(c!) ?? "Probably overflowed"`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It doesn't have to return anything. It's playground and also - if it would have return any value, the function would end with -> ValueType

Comment: What difference does the playground make, @pedrouan?

Comment: That is doesn't matter, that it doesn't return anything, in playground you see result on the right side at the line level. http://pasteboard.co/d0gahjzBU.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on here:

1. `a` overflows, becaue `128` is larger than the maximum value that can be stored in an `Int8` (`Int8.max` = `127`), thus it'll return `nil`.

   This `nil`, a.k.a. `Optional.None` is of type `Optional<Int8>` is not the type specified by the type annotation of `a` (`Int8??`, a.k.a. `Optional<Optional<Int8>>`), so it's wrapped in another optional, becoming `Optional.Some(Optional.None)`, which is now the correct type.
2. `nilCoalescing()` doesn't return anything. (Which actually means it returns `()`, a.k.a. `Void`)
3. Don't do this explicit `nil` check and force unwrap (`!`): `a != nil ? a! : b`. Use `??` instead: `a ?? b`

What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: "This nil, a.k.a. Optional.None is then wrapped in another optional so it becomes Optional.Some(Optional.None)" This is probably the key to the OP's confusion.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's what I suspect, but honestly I don't know. This is all quite nonsensical lol

Comment: I occationally tried to assign nil to variable **a** two times.

Comment: @uncleFedex Okay, and?

Comment: It does not matter if you use `a != nil ? a! : b` or `a ?? b`, those expressions are (almost) equivalent. In both cases, `a` is *not* nil (it is `Optional.Some(Optional.None)` as you correctly said). Therefore the expression evaluates to `a!` which is `Optional.None` aka `nil`.

Comment: @MartinR I intentionally mentioned it because it has the same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

128 overflows when converted to Int8 so it is stored as nil.